# How to create Except character limit of string length in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper, codeigniter-form-helper

I'm build a website application in Codeigniter latest version and I want to use exception function to cut or limit my text in case don't allow that text to break my web layout.

This below I will break my text (to show only short word) by using space between one word to another word.

**But I want to create a function to break or cut by characters or length of whole string**

***Example: if I have 2000 character of string length but I want to show only 100 characters of string length (count bother spaces and special character)***

```
function My_EXCEPTION($string, $limit, $break=" ", $pad="...")
{
    if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string;
    if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))) {
        if($breakpoint < explode(strlen($string),-1)) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad;
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

How could I do with this function Please help

Thanks you in advance!!!

Comment: You can use text helper
    
   character_limiter($string, 100)

Answer (score 0):

Now My problem is solved by my coding as below

```
function My_EXEPTION($string, $limit, $break = " ", $readmore = "...") {
    if(strlen($string) <= $limit) {
        return $string;
    }
    if($limit < explode(strlen($string), 0)) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $limit) . $readmore;
        return $string;
    }
}
```

It might can help to someone who want it